# Windows Vista not booting after deleting a partition

Tags: linux, windows-vista, boot, partitioning

My cousin just deleted his Linux partition and another smaller partitio nand now Windows is not booting, **no he does not have the recovery disc.** When Windows tries to boot it goes to "GRUB" and says "partition not loaded". What are some GRUB commands? And is it possible to fix this without using the recovery CD? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like he has deleted the 100Mb boot partition, or deleted and messed up the Windows boot loader.

If he doesn't have a recovery disk, the best thing you can do is simply [download a trial disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx?ITPID=neweffc) and burn it then boot from it.

Windows PE should load (The installation environment) then choose the option to repair your machine.

It should detect the problem and either (I am not to sure which), recreate the partition and copy the boot files or simply copy the boot loader and files to the active/primary partition.

This will most likely delete GRUB, but next time you load, everything should be fine.

The trial link is for Windows 7 Enterprise as that is all I could quickly find. Windows Vista and 7 bootloaders are compatible with each other.

If however it does not automatically fix the problem, you can choose `Command Prompt` as a repair option, then manually rebuild the boot sector.

Go in to `Diskpart` and make sure the main Windows drive is active (or recreate the 100Mb partition and set that to active).

Next, type the following:

> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /rebuildbcd

This should, scan for errors, fix and rebuild the boot sector and repopulate the menu.

(If you want to read more about Bootrec, [click here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392))

Comment: It looks more like GRUB is referring to files on the Linux Partition which are no longer there.

Comment: Running those bootrec commands that Wil mentioned should replace the grub bootloader with the windows bootloader and fix Vista.