# Missing autochk program during boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I just resized a windows partition which involved shifting about 160GB to the left. After that it couldn't find the boot like normal so I ran the system repair tool like normal(I resize this partition a lot and each time I have to use the repair disk).

But, this time, when I rebooted into the recovered 7 partition, it displayed the windows logo like normal but then flashed up

> autochk program not found -- skipping autocheck

After that being on the screen for about 8 seconds, there was a flash of a bluescreen with white text and it rebooted. I have tried running the repair disk multiple times, but it returns and fixes the same problem each time, and the same thing happens on boot each time. Is there anything I can do to fix this short of reinstalling Windows?

I have also ran two chkdsks from my vista partition with no errors reported and when  viewing all the files on the drive everything seems to be in place.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem, and none of the fixboot/fixmbr/bootrec commands helped. Here's what did fix it:

It appears that the C: is mismapped for whatever reason. In my case, I guess it's because my migration software didn't find it.

Boot into the recovery console and launch regedit.

```
 For those not used to this language, that means: 
 - Boot from the Win7 disk 
 - At the "Install Windows" screen press SHIFT F10 to get a command window 
 - Type "regedit" (without the "") 
 - and press Enter
```

Select the HKLM hive and then use "load hive" to mount your c:\windows\system32\config\system hive (I name it 'offline'). You have to select HKLM so that Load Hive will be enabled, we're not actually going to load the offline hive into it.

```
 For those not used to this language, that means: 
 - Click to Select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
 - Click File, Load Hive
 - Click the drop down arrow in "Look in"
 - Browse to C:\Windows\System32\config
 - Select SYSTEM and click Open
 - In Key Name type "offline"
 - OK
```

Now you're going to compare HKLM\System\MountedDevices (which is the recovery environment's device list) to HKLM\System\Offline\MountedDevices (which is the one for your failing windows install). In my case, I found that the recovery environment was correctly seeing C:, but the offline hive had the wrong disk signature for c:. (possibly because I deleted a recovery partition as part of the migration. So we need to put the right signature.

Look at the binary entry for DosDevices\C: in the recovery registry. Now go to the offline registry and fix your DosDevices\C: so it matches. In my case, I found it easiest to rename the bad DosDevices\C: to Z:, and then go through the \volume{guid} entries until I found the one that matches the working C:, and then rename that one to DosDevices\C:.

Unload the hive in the file menu, and then reboot. After I did that, I was able to boot.

```
 For those not used to this language, that means: 
 - Select "offline" in the left hand pane
 - Click File, Unload Hive
 - Yes
 - Close Registry Editor and the Command Window
 - Close the "Install Windows" screen
 - Yes
 - Remove the Win7 disk and boot into Win7.
```

Other internet searches implied that simply deleting all the offline DosDevices entries would force them to get correctly recreated, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: Fantastic, I can't believe it but this actually fixed it! As Gregor noted, "Load Hive" won't appear unless you have HKLM (HKeyLocalMachine) selected

Comment: I was able to revive a Windows 2008 R2 domain controller using the information listed above.  When resizing a partition, we accidentally killed the 100MB recovery partition.  First I had to do **bcdboot c:\windows** and **bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr /force** from the recovery console command line to make the drive bootable.  Then I was able to use regedit to fix the C: mapping.  In my case, DosDevices\C: was missing from the registry.

Comment: Protip for using Load Hive in regedit: You have to click one of the HKLM, HKCU, etc hives before it will work. It took me a while to figure out why this option was greyed out! You could also use REG LOAD from the command prompt before launching regedit.

Answer (score 1):

The blue screen of death error usually find in Windows system and this is typically caused by software errors in device drivers.

The Blue screen treatment, you can refer to

1 restart

2 new hardware detection of new services

3 Trojan virus detected

4 checks BIOS and hardware compatibility

5 run “sfc / scannow” system to check whether documents have been replaced, and then use the installation disk to restore the system

you can try to boot your windows system in safe mode by pressing F8 repeatedly when you restart your computer.

Comment: It's not the bsod, I know that for a fact, and that isn't the main problem. I cant even boot into safemode because of this autocheck program, and for some reason I can't run sfc.

Comment: @Ok sandwhich: can you please tell me when you are running the command of sfc what exact message you are getting? or not getting any message?

Comment: I posted in the comments above the error message.

Comment: I have another crap vista install, would I be able to run sfc from that?

Answer (score 1):

Reasons I can see for such a problem :

- You may have reduced the system
  partition below its minimum size by
  using a 3rd-party partitioner
- You may have changed the number of
  the partition by creating a new
  preceding partition
- A copy error has occurred while
  moving the partition

In all cases, if you cannot undo the damage, and if the recovery options in the Windows 7 boot CD do not fix the problem, you may need to [Do a Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html). This will fix your currently installed Windows 7, while still preserving user accounts, data, programs, and system drivers (but ensure you have backups anyway).

Comment: I can't boot into windows, and that tutorial requires you to boot into windows. Is it possible to do a repair install without booting into windows? I think I would be able to fix it if I were to somehow force sfc to run, but for some reason I can't.

Comment: You can also start it from the Windows 7 boot CD.

Comment: Boot cd? The installation dvd?

Comment: Yes, installation dvd.

Comment: Whenever I boot into my install dvd, It goes straight into installation, how do I launch a repair install?

Comment: In the next screen after language preferences you should have a "Repair your computer" option at the bottom.

Comment: There isn't anything at the bottom other than the little status bar that spans the screen.

Comment: This means that Windows doesn't identify the partition as a Windows installation, in other words the partition is destroyed. I hope that you have taken a backup image of the partition as it was before the resize. If not, then you will need to reinstall Windows, and perhaps in the future use another partitioning tool than the one that destroyed it this time (and take better backups).

Comment: Ok. I guess Ill just reinstall windows.

Comment: Is it not possible to force sfc to run or remove the system repair flags?

Comment: sfc requires boot.

Answer (score 1):

Yostage, your Tutorial fixed the problem for me. I want to note that "load Hive" only works when you have selected HKLM. I had to try around a bit until I found out how it works.

And what do you know? Both `DosDevices\C:` entries were different. Fixed the wrong one, and Windows 7 booted without any problem.

I had Windows 7 on the 3rd partition on my primary HDD (500GB) of my Laptop. Then I deleted the 2nd partition, because I didn't needed it anymore, and added the free space to partition 1. This may have been the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar but not duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/145582/windows-vista-not-booting-after-deleting-a-partition/145585#145585), so repeating my answer slightly.

It sounds to me like the 100Mb boot partition, has become deleted or part of the Windows boot loader has become faulty.

If you are not able to automatically recover using the startup recovery tool, you can choose `Command Prompt` as a repair option, then manually rebuild the boot sector.

Type the following:

> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /rebuildbcd

This should, scan for errors, fix and rebuild the boot sector and repopulate the menu.

(If you want to read more about Bootrec, [click here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392))

Comment: Wil, interesting read here, not directly related to this post but very interesting...http://blog.jitbit.com/2011/04/rootkit-on-brand-new-toshiba-laptop.html

Comment: Well, I did that. It said all operations were completed successfully, but the last one said it found a total of 0 windows installs, so I am thinking that might be a problem. I rebooted and the same thing happened. Should I be navigate to the correct drive before doing this?

Comment: @A Sandwhich, you won't like it, but if it couldn't find a Windows Install, you may be best of just reinstalling Windows.

Comment: If I do reinstall, will there be a way to retain all of my current files?

Comment: @Moab - Wow... Just wow...

Comment: Would it be possible to manually go in and replace the autocheck program?

Comment: I just searched the partition containing 7 for autochk.exe and 10 files turned up.

Comment: @ a sandwhich, try using SFC...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: I did, and each time I do it from the repair disc it says there is a system repair pending which requires a reboot to continue, restart windiws and run sf again.

Comment: @ a sandwhich, see this article for running it from DVD...http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-sfc-offline-windows-7-vista/

Comment: @ Wil, crazy stuff eh?

Comment: That is what I did. And each time I did it, it said there was a system repair waiting and that I need to reboot to run sfc. Each time I reboot into the windows re it says the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up doing a clean reinstall. Some of the files were left under a windows.old folder, can I just copy the programs into the new program files folder and expect them to work fine? Programs such as (cs4, iTunes, lightwave, maya, steam, crysis 2, other non steam games)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Yostage's answer and reasoning, I found a another solution. Worked for me at least.

The goal is to make your system assign the new/editted partition as C: again.
A Win7 disk is still needed.

```
1) Boot from a Win7 disk
2) At the "Install Windows" screen press SHIFT F10 to get a command window 
3) Type "diskpart"          (without the "")
```

This loads the MS DiskPart command-line application. Now inside diskpart:

```
4) Type "list disk"         and find the disk # of the boot drive
5) Type "select disk #"     where # is the # noted before
6) Type "list part"         and find the part # of the boot partition (the one labelled "Primary")
7) Type "select part #"     where # is the # noted before
8) Type "assign letter=C"
```

Diskpart will then confirm that the letter has been successfully assigned to the partition.

You can shut down the system, eject the Win7 Disk, and boot from your drive once again.